# Testing content in POMs for multi-module Maven project

Tags: maven, unit-testing, integration-testing, surefire, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have read [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Maven+and+Integration+Testing) about unit testing with the Surefire plugin and integration testing with the Failsafe plugin, but I am still unclear about how the POMs should look in a Maven project that consists of a parent and multiple child modules, each with their own POM file.

**Questions**:

- Has anyone implemented integration tests and unit tests in each of their modules?
- If so, would you be so kind as to show your POMs so I have an example of a good working configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See my answer to question: [How can I switch between two test suites in Maven 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533401/how-can-i-switch-between-two-test-suites-in-maven-2/9533540#9533540)
I prefer maven module - very easy to implement and you do not need knowledge about other plugin.

If you using [testng](/questions/tagged/testng) you can just define in your parent pom (one place only):

```
<profile>
    <id>normal</id>
    <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludedGroups>integration</excludedGroups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    </profile>
<profile>
    <id>integration</id>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includedGroups>integration</includedGroups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</profile>
```

Annotate all integration tests by:

```
@Test(groups="integration")
```

If you use junit see [Category](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/doc/ReleaseNotes4.8.html)

You run normal test by: `mvn clean install` integration tests by `mvn -Pintegration clean install`

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Stanbol](http://incubator.apache.org/stanbol/) project uses surefire plugin for unit tests and integration tests. It can be a good example for you.

Here are the links: [parent module](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/stanbol/trunk/parent/pom.xml), [integration-tests](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/stanbol/trunk/integration-tests/pom.xml) and one of the components of Stanbol that has its own unit tests, [factstore](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/stanbol/trunk/factstore/factstore/pom.xml).